# Whenever i use while(cin>>(var)) in my code, the istream gets stuck in error state

Tags: c++, error-handling, while-loop, istream

The code i am trying to run is given below. Here in **line 9** I am trying to take multiple inputs using the `while(cin>>n)` method. The input I gave is like :

```
2 4 5 6 45 357 3 (ctrl+z)(ctrl+z)
```

to indicate EOF in windows.

Then, even thought the numbers get added into the vector `v1`, the `istream` is stuck into error state cause the output I get this :

```
error2 4 5 6 45 357 3.
```

And I can also confirm that istream is stuck in error state cause if I use another `cin` statement after this, it gets ignored by the compiler until I clear the stream by `cin.clear()` function.

Can anybody please tell me why does this happen and how can I prevent the stream getting into error state. or is it something normal and I must use `cin.clear()` after every while(cin>>(var)) statement?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using std:: cin; using std:: cout; using std::endl;using std::vector;
int main(){
vector<int> v1;
int n;
cout<< "enter the list of numbers";
while(cin>>n){
    v1.push_back(n);
}
if((cin>>n).fail()){cout<<"error";}
for (auto i: v1){
    cout<< i<<" ";
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/c54dGdWcq

Comment: There are cases where `failbit` could be set at the same time as `eofbit`. Check for `eof` first, and if false check for `fail`. If `eof` is set you can't read more. If `fail` is set you need to `clear` the status and attempt again.

Comment: Well, the first `while` loop only ends when reading `std::cin` fails, that's what `while(cin >>n)` means, so what exactly is your question about the code showing the error, because `std::cin` must be in a failed state, by then?

Comment: Yes this happens by design. Once stream is in error state you have to clear error flags to continue using it.

Comment: Maybe you should read [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate)?

Comment: the result of `cin>>n` **is** `cin` itself, not some `bool`

Comment: @appleapple  I do not understand your comment. Yes `cin>>n` returns `cin`. But then `cin`has a `bool` operator. And hence, you can use the complete statement as a boolean expression.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i checked `eof` is false when i enter `ctrl+z``ctrl+z` twice in the same line in the terminal but if i first press `enter` and then `ctrl+z` ,`eof` becomes true.

Comment: @MarekR So is it completely natural for the istream to go into error state after using a`while(cin>>*variable*) `statement? And i am doing nothing wrong here?

Comment: @ArminMontigny Just in case OP think it return the result of **current operation**, which is probably how this question comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the statement `cin>>n` return the `cin` object itself, put it inside `while` does something like

```cpp
while(true){
   cin >> n;
   if(cin){ // equals to if(!cin.fail())
      // ... body of while
   }
   else break;
}
```

so yes, after you leave the loop, `cin` is [in `fail` state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), thus any subsequence `operator >>` would not success until you call [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).

---

relevant: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate